# On macOS why "ps" always shows session id as "0"

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, shell, process

I noticed it when running `ps` on different terminal sessions...

I don't really understand why? Also, when killing the `-zsh` process, so the interactive login shell, I noticed every of its children are killed too.

Who does that? Is it the OS that kills every process remaining when the login shell is killed? If so, how does he does it, because the sessionid is "0" for all.

[image: attached terminal picture]

Comment: Actual answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248294/does-os-x-support-posix-sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Session ID

The session ID is actually pid of `iTerm2 --server login -fp` in this case, `ps` in OS X doesn't show it correctly though. You can confirm it with below C code.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <unistd.h>
  3 
  4 int main() {
  5   printf("pid: %d, process groupd id: %d, session ID: %d, ppid: %d\n",getpid(), getpgid(0), getsid(0), getppid());
  6 }
```

```
$ gcc getsid.c -o getsid ; ./getsid
pid: 25472, process groupd id: 25472, session ID: 25236, ppid: 25239
```

The session leader is process 25236, which is `iTerm2 --server login -fp`

```
$ pstree -p $$
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 25234 shaobirui /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
   \-+= 25236 shaobirui /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp shaobirui
     \-+= 25237 root login -fp shaobirui
       \-+= 25239 shaobirui -bash
         \-+= 25329 shaobirui pstree -p 25239
           \--- 25330 root ps -axwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
```

The other neat way is to check `STAT` field, you can see `Ss`, the second lower `s` actually means session leader.

```
$ ps -j
USER        PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
shaobirui 25236 25234 25236      0    0 Ss   s000    0:00.03 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp shaobirui
shaobirui 25239 25237 25239      0    1 S    s000    0:00.05 -bash
```

## Why Children Got Killed?

When session leader exits, it will send SIGHUP to all its descendants, which terminates processes by default. I reproduce it in two terminal emulators: iTerm2 and OS X termianl.

### in iTerm2:

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys000

$ cat test.sh
trap "echo $$ got SIGUP > /tmp/out.txt;exit" 1
echo $$ is sleeping
sleep 5555

$ bash test.sh
25000 is sleeping
```

### in OS X terminal:

```
$ pstree -p 25000
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 24875 shaobirui /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
   \-+= 24877 shaobirui /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp shaobirui
     \-+= 24878 root login -fp shaobirui
       \-+= 24879 shaobirui -bash
         \-+= 25000 shaobirui bash test.sh
           \--- 25001 shaobirui sleep 5555

$ ps -j -o tpgid 24875 24878 24879 25000 25001
USER        PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND          TPGID
shaobirui 24875     1 24875      0    1 S      ??    0:07.97 /Applications/iT     0
shaobirui 24877 24875 24877      0    0 Ss   s000    0:00.04 /Applications/iT 25000
shaobirui 24879 24878 24879      0    1 S    s000    0:00.03 -bash            25000
shaobirui 25000 24879 25000      0    1 S+   s000    0:00.00 bash test.sh     25000
shaobirui 25001 25000 25000      0    1 S+   s000    0:00.00 sleep 5555       25000
shaobirui 22134 22133 22134      0    1 S    s001    0:00.40 -bash            25021

$ kill 24877

# all processes in that session are gone due to SIGHUP
$ ps -j -o tpgid 24875 24878 24879 25000 25001
USER        PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND TPGID
shaobirui 22134 22133 22134      0    1 S    s001    0:00.41 -bash   25032

$ cat /tmp/out.txt 
25000 got SIGUP
```